# VisualForce error - Custom Button to add existing records

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-button

I am receiving the following Error: 
Unknown property 'AddExistingSpecsExt.Specifications__c' Line 0

VisualForce Code

```
<apex:page controller="AddExistingSpecsExt">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock title="Associate Specifications to Products">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageblockbuttons location="top">
                <apex:commandbutton value="Associate" action="{!associate}" />
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Specification Name</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputText>{!Specifications__c.Name}</apex:outputText>   
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Specifications</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Specifications__r.Product__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class AddExistingSpecsExt {

    public Specifications__c loadedSpec { get; private set; }

public AddExistingSpecsExt() {
    String specId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    if (String.isBlank(specId)) return;

    List<Specifications__c> candidates = [
        SELECT Id, Name, Product__c FROM Specifications__c WHERE Id = :specId LIMIT 1
    ];
    if (!candidates.isEmpty()) loadedSpec = candidates[0];
}
    public PageReference associate () {

        Specifications__c candidates = new Specifications__c ( Id = loadedSpec.Product__c, Name =loadedSpec.Id);

        try {
            Database.update(candidates);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error while associating.' + error.getMessage()));
        }

        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + candidates);

        return page.setRedirect(true);
    }

    public PageReference cancel () {
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + Null);
        return page.setRedirect(true);        
    }

}
```

Comment: Try selecting your whole code block and hitting `ctrl+k` next time.

Comment: You are facing the same issue as your previous post, just now it's in the markup instead.

Comment: What are the Mac hot keys for the code block recommendation you have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your variable  name is `loadedSpec` in controller

And your variable  contains all the value

Inorder to the value you need to access variable not the object i.e. `Specifications__c`

So when you initialize object `Specifications__c` and give parameter name.

You have to use that parameter, in your case i.e `loadedSpec`

Change

```
<apex:outputText>{!Specifications__c.Name}</apex:outputText> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Specifications__r.Product__c}"/>
```

to

```
<apex:outputText>{!loadedSpec.Name}</apex:outputText>
<apex:inputField value="{!loadedSpec.Product__c}"/>
```

Comment: Can you also explain why e.g. no standard controller?

Comment: Got it. your the best.

Comment: @KeithC In the context of their Jason's previous posts, that is not likely the source of confusion here, though it would add depth.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't have the history here, but do feel that answers should try to educate rather than just being code that is cut and pasted.

Comment: I want to understand what is happening so I can avoid making the same mistakes for the future. So educational posts would be beneficial for me.

Comment: @Jason Does my ans make sense?

Comment: @Ratan yes that answer makes sense, I was able to fix the issues I was having with that. That was good. I was just elaborating on what Keith C wrote.